# ios subclassing error casting subclass

Tags: objective-c, subclass, nsobject

I have a Widget class of nsobject with some properties and some methods, then I have a Widget subclass called Gallery, this class has some method and some properties...
When I fetch data from web I save all data into Widget object, if one of this obj has a specific class_id (class_id is a property) then I would create a Gallery object, for do this I do something like this:

```
Widget *w = [[Widget alloc] init];
Widget *w_1,*w_2,.....
NSArray *a = @[w,w_1,w_2,ecc];

Gallery *g = (Gallery *)[a objectAtIndex:2];
```

doing this if I check g class I see Widget class, and then if I try to run Gallery methods I get "unrecognized selector sent"....where is the mistake?

Comment: Well from the code you are supplying non of the objects in the array is of type Gallery?

Comment: yes, the array's object are "Widget" type, but Gallery is a subclass of Widget, so in the theory I can do the cast

Comment: No downcasting will not work since it's not the actual type. Downcasting only works when the actual type is the one you are casting to. The other way around works tho, making a Gallery a Widget. It's very logical ... since you have not allocated a Gallery but just a part of it (the super class) it can't magically become a Gallery later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was: Where is the mistake?

The mistake you make is your assumption that casting a Widget* to a Gallery* turns the object from a Widget object to a Gallery object. It doesn't. The cast doesn't change what the object is. The cast only changes what the compiler thinks the object is.

Because the compiler *thinks* incorrectly that it has a Gallery object, it allows you to send a Gallery method to the object without complaining. But it is still a Widget object receiving the message, it doesn't understand it, so your program crashes.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line, you are `alloc / init` a Widget class... You are then trying to cast the `Widget` as a `Gallery`. Even thought you're casting a `Widget` as a `Gallery`, it is still a `Widget` class, since you `alloc / init` it as a `Widget`.

What you need to do is check if the `class_id` is a `Gallery`, and if it is, `alloc / init` as a `Gallery` object instead of a `Widget` object. Then you will gain access to the properties and functions of a `Gallery`. Example:

```
Widget *widget = nil;
if([class_id isEqualToString:gallary_id]) {
    widget = [[Gallery alloc] init];
}
else { 
    widget = [[Widget alloc] init];
}
```

Hope this helps.